# C - What does free() do to the memory?

Tags: c, malloc, free

I recoded `malloc()` `free()` and `realloc()`.

I have a linked list with the pointers returned by `malloc()`.

The question is : what does `free()` really do ?

Currently, I did a `memset()` to have the same behavior of `free()`.

But was it better just to set a flag in my list as 'is free' rather than doing a `memset()` in order to make it faster ?

Comment: `I recoded` what do you mean?

Comment: I have never read the implementation of `free()` but it's behavior is not the one you apparently think, `free()` doesn't set the memory to `0` it just releases it to the OS so it can be accessible by someone else, but it does not zero the bytes.

Comment: If your malloc() implementation uses a linked list, free() should put the freed memory on the free-list.

Comment: @MariusSiuram I'm recoding it and using `LD_PRELOAD` to test it.
@iharob Okay, but if i'm not setting it to 0, for example we can still print a pointer which has been freed, which is not possible with the system free. That's why I thought it was good to do a `memset()`. By the way, the memset still allows me to use the pointer for a next `malloc()`. So is that good too ?
@wildplasser I don't have a free-list but just a flag in my list to tell if it is free or not, thought it was a better way to do it, am i wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually free(3) does not do anything to the memory itself. (If security or privacy is a concern, you should clear memory before freeing.)

If you want to implement malloc, you need to have some database of free memory blocks. When memory is freed you should join it with adjoint free memory, if there is any. If a complete page ends up unused, you should tell the kernel, that you don't need it anymore (depending on how you got that memory in the first place)

Comment: Okay, so if I use `memset` it's not like the system call, but do you personnaly think it's a good way to do like I did ? Is it safe or am I missing something ?

Comment: @nookonee free() would normally return the memory to the memory allocator, so the memory can be used again in future calls to malloc(). That's a very different thing compared to what memset() does.

Comment: @nos Okay, currently I have a list with all my adresses and a flag to say if it is free or not. So I am setting this flag and doing the `memset` So as it, I can reuse it and it is set to 0, is that right ?

Comment: @Leonard Michlmayr No free won't deallocate the memory allocated to it at all right? Because I just tried malloc()ing a char * of length 15, putting a random sentence into it, printing that sentence, freeing the char *, and then printing the same char * variable and got the same sentence. So it doesn't really seem like the memory has been deallocated, no?

Comment: @z.karl, as I said, free does not change the data in the memory. It's like leaving your table in a fast food restaurant. If you decide to come back later your tray may still be there, but there is no guarantee. If you want to make sure that the data is cleared, use memset before free. That's the way to clear your table. If you don't use memset (which is the way you would do it most of the time) the next customer will remove your tray. (Note that if you want to make sure that no data leaks to other processes, memset is not enough.)

Comment: @LeonardMichlmayr ahhh, thanks! I really like the fast food analogy!

Answer (score 4):

**Free :** Call will unlink / unallocate the memory pointed by pointer so that  other process can use it.

**Memset :** Call will set a memory / fill a memory location. It won't unlink / unallocate a memory and memory remain allocated / occupied till the program exist. Which can cause memory leaks.

You can use **valgrind** tool to check memory leaks.

And it is a better practice to unlink / unallocate a memory if its not required.

Answer (score 2):

The C library function `void free(void *ptr)` deallocates the memory previously allocated by a call to `calloc`, `malloc`, or `realloc`.

You should use it to prevent memory leaks.

Comment: is this truly what free() does? Because I just tried malloc()ing a char * of length 15, putting a random sentence into it, printing that sentence, freeing the char *, and then printing the same char * variable and got the same sentence. So it doesn't really seem like the memory has been deallocated, no?

Comment: @z.karl You seem to think "deallocated" means something which it doesn't mean. It is no longer reserved for your use; it no longer belongs to you. Whether it still contains some stuff you put there after you give it up is implementation-defined and unpredictable, especially over time.

Comment: @tripleee ah, thank you for pointing that misunderstanding out. So free() seems to be a lot like the `rm` linux command where it unlinks the memory/file in question, and it may or may not be where it was before, but whatever is in there isn't determined by what was before no?

Comment: I woudn't exactly phrase it like that. Typically it doesn't make sense to eraee a resource when it's released, but it could become reserved for something else and have its contents replaced at any point. System load and the OS allocation strategy influecnce whether that's likely to happen sooner rather than later; typical Unix file systems will reclaim the released space fairly soon, whereas some other file systems will try to leave things untouched for longer, e.g. to reduce fragmentation. Your exposition still seems to confuse position (address) - which can never change - with contents.